# Automated Nuspec Package Creation

Tags: jenkins, automation, nuget-package, nuspec

#### Problem

So I am working on a feature to allow my team the ability to create NuGet Packages of specific projects automatically upon the project building successfully in Jenkins. I have spent the last 3 days researching how to contruct/create/build `nuspec` packages and `NuGet` packages... but nothing seems to point me in quite the same direction I am trying to take this in.

So far, from what I have learned and understood about creating `NuGet` packages, the primary way to do this is the following steps:

1. Download `nuget.exe` and place a copy of it in the target project's root folder.
2. Open the cmdprompt and navigate to the target project's root folder
3. Run the following command `nuget spec`
4. Open the newly created `nuspect` file and update all default values to the appropriate values for the target project
5. Save the changes, then run the following command in the cmdprompt `nuget pack packagename.nuspec`

Although the above works as expect, it isn't really very automated.

I have taken an approach in which I created a script that has a `nuspec` template and populates fields, but I still require a lot of input from the user to make this happen.

#### Question

Is there any way to automatically generate a properly populated `nuspec` package for a target project that requires minimal input from a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Package.Builder/) on NuGet that

- Works well in a continuous integration environment with a build server; and
- Creates a nuspec file for your project.

Source code with a larger readme is on [Github](https://github.com/LarsSkovslund/NuGet.Package.Builder/)

Comment: Oh, how did I not run into this during my research...? This is very close to what I am trying to achieve. I can definitely work with this. Thank you